# Many ViewExpiredException happens in my JSF 2 / Icefaces 3 application

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces-3

In my application JSF 2 I have many ViewExpiredException occurring. Even on the authentication page. When it happens during authenticate we should re enter the login / password for it to work. On other pages we need to refresh (F5) the browser. On IE11 is almost systematic. I think I have a problem of cache because it frequently show old pages.

JSF configuration :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
  "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>

    <display-name>OMB</display-name>
    <description>OMB</description>

    <!-- Without this param upload does not work at 1st time with IceFaces 3.3.0 -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.icefaces.mandatoryResourceConfiguration</param-name>
        <param-value>all</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/pages/templates/tags.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/appCtx/**/*applicationContext*.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!-- Facelet Config -->
    <!-- <context-param> <param-name>javax.faces.application.CONFIG_FILES</param-name> 
        <param-value> /WEB-INF/faces-config-application-beans.xml, /WEB-INF/faces-config-navigation.xml 
        </param-value> </context-param> -->
    <!-- <context-param> <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name> 
        <param-value>Development</param-value> </context-param> -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
        <param-value>-1</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.standardRequestScope</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Specifies to the ICEfaces framework whether to support multiple views 
        of a single application from the same browser. When running in a Portlet 
        environment, this parameter must be set to true. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.concurrentDOMViews</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Specifies to the ICEfaces framework that synchronous update mode is 
        to be used. By default, ICEfaces uses asynchronous update mode to support 
        server-initiated updates (AJAX push). Setting to true will enable synchronous 
        update mode and disable AJAX push features. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.synchronousUpdate</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Specifies to the ICEfaces framework whether to compress the server-side 
        DOM representation after each response. This saves a considerable amount 
        of of memory per client. However, since this is decompressed/compressed for 
        every update, it may not bring significant memory savings to applications 
        that make frequent use of AJAX push. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.compressDOM</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Specifies the amount of time in milliseconds that the bridge will wait 
        for a response from the server for a user-initiated request before declaring 
        the connection lost. Un-comment and change the default value, if necessary. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.connectionTimeout</param-name>
        <param-value>300000</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!-- Specifies the amount of time in milliseconds that an idle asynchronous 
        blocking connection should be held open before being released. Normally, 
        the blocking connection is closed and re-opened with every communication 
        to the browser, such as user interaction or a heartbeat ping. The purpose 
        of this setting is to remove the possibility of threads being held blocked 
        for a long duration on a dead or completely inactive client connection. This 
        value should be longer than the heartbeat interval to avoid unnecessary network 
        traffic. Un-comment and change the default value, if necessary. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>
            com.icesoft.faces.blockingConnectionTimeout
        </param-name>
        <param-value>90000</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!-- Specifies the amount of time in milliseconds between heartbeat messages. 
        Un-comment and change the default value, if necessary. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.heartbeatInterval</param-name>
        <param-value>50000</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!-- Specifies how many consecutive heartbeat connection attempts may fail 
        before the connection is considered lost. Un-comment and change the default 
        value, if necessary. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.heartbeatRetries</param-name>
        <param-value>2</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!-- Specifies the number of milliseconds that a heartbeat request waits 
        for a successful response before it is considered timed out. Un-comment and 
        change the default value, if necessary. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.heartbeatTimeout</param-name>
        <param-value>60000</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!-- Specifies a page URI to redirect the client to when an asynchronous 
        connection is lost. The parameter value must be surrounded by single quotes. 
        Un-comment and change the default value, if necessary. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>
            com.icesoft.faces.connectionLostRedirectURI
        </param-name>
        <param-value>login.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>
            com.icesoft.faces.sessionExpiredRedirectURI
        </param-name>
        <param-value>login.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.blockUIOnSubmit</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.icefaces.ace.fileEntry.requireJavascript</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jExposeWebAppRoot</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>HttpHeadersFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.omb.filters.HttpHeadersFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>X-UA-Compatible</param-name>
            <param-value>IE=9</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>HttpHeadersFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- SPRING -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Listener d'initialisation de l'application -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.omb.listeners.OMBServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Faces Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.CompatResourceServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/icefaces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/xmlhttp/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>com</extension>
        <mime-type>application/octet-stream</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>com</extension>
        <mime-type>text/plain</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>pdf</extension>
        <mime-type>application/pdf</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

    <!-- Welcome files -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/pages/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.RuntimeException</exception-type>
        <location>/pages/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

ExceptionHandler :

```
package com.omb.view.exception;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.faces.FacesException;
import javax.faces.application.NavigationHandler;
import javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException;
import javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandler;
import javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerWrapper;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ExceptionQueuedEvent;
import javax.faces.event.ExceptionQueuedEventContext;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.icefaces.application.SessionExpiredException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.omb.UserContext;
import com.omb.exception.FunctionnalException;
import com.omb.service.translation.TranslationService;
import com.omb.view.util.FacesUtils;


public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandlerWrapper {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(CustomExceptionHandler.class);
    private ExceptionHandler wrapped;

    @Autowired
    private TranslationService translationService;

    @Autowired
    private UserContext userContext;

    CustomExceptionHandler(ExceptionHandler exception) {
        this.wrapped = exception;
    }

    /**
     * @see javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerWrapper#getWrapped()
     */
    @Override
    public ExceptionHandler getWrapped() {
        return wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle() throws FacesException {
        final Iterator<ExceptionQueuedEvent> i = getUnhandledExceptionQueuedEvents().iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            ExceptionQueuedEvent event = i.next();
            ExceptionQueuedEventContext context =
                    (ExceptionQueuedEventContext) event.getSource();

            // get the exception from context
            Throwable throwable = context.getException();

            final FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            final Map<String, Object> requestMap = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestMap();
            final NavigationHandler nav = fc.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();

            // here you do what ever you want with exception
            try {

                if (throwable instanceof ViewExpiredException) {

                    logger.info("the session is expired");
                    FacesUtils.addInfoMessage("Session expired !");
                    nav.handleNavigation(fc, null, "sessionExpired");

                } else if (throwable instanceof SessionExpiredException) {

                    nav.handleNavigation(fc, null, "sessionExpired");

                } else if (throwable instanceof FunctionnalException) {

                    logger.warn(throwable.getMessage());
                    FacesUtils.addInfoMessage(throwable.getMessage());
                    nav.handleNavigation(fc, null, null);

                } else {

                    logger.error(throwable.getMessage(), throwable);
                    requestMap.put("exceptionMessage", throwable.getMessage());
                    nav.handleNavigation(fc, null, "error");

                }

                fc.renderResponse();

            } finally {
                // remove it from queue
                i.remove();
            }
        }
        // parent hanle
        getWrapped().handle();
    }

}
```

Comment: Your web application is running in Servlet 2.3 fallback compatibility modus. This doesn't make any sense. JSF 2.x requires a minimum of Servlet 2.5 and for JSF 2.2 this is even Servlet 3.0. Get rid of that Servlet 2.3 `<!DOCTYPE>` in `web.xml` and alter `<web-app>` accordingly to declare the highest version supported by the target container and retry. That should at least eliminate a big probable cause. You can find proper `<web-app>` declaration examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30778598

Comment: Yes it's true I had not seen. The application was created before my arrival on the project ... Think you that this is the main cause of our problem ?

Comment: We basically can't tell for sure without seeing the entire project. There are too many probable causes for this problem which are not all visible/excludable based on the information posted so far. That's exactly why I posted it as a comment instead of an answer and explicitly mentioned "retry" and "a big probable cause". To have a more specific and suitable answer, you have to debug and investigate yourself why exactly the views aren't reused and then tell it in the question. This only requires a bit of basic knowledge of HTTP and Java.

Comment: To start, this should provide sufficient background information:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/3642919